# Find match in database with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

So this is the problem for which I need solving: Users in my database are following a certain amount of courses. These courses are all numbered, so the value of the row `courses` could be `12, 34, 56` or `12` or '', etc. Now I'm doing a search query to find users that are following a certain course. I was thinking about using `LIKE`, but it seems like an impractical solution, because then I have to match it as follows:

`courses LIKE '$course,%' OR courses LIKE '%,$course,%' OR courses LIKE '%,$course' OR courses LIKE '$course'`

Since there are four different ways to match, I was hoping for a better solution, but haven't thought of anything yet myself. Anybody with a creative solution? Thanks a mil.

Comment: So are you trying to retrieve data using course name or course id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL has implemented a function called `FIND_IN_SET()` that searches a value from a comma separated value, eg

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableName
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('12', 'comma separated value') > 0
```

- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Consider normalizing your tables. Storing comman separated value in a single column is such a bad idea.

Comment: just drop by a comment if you have further questions.

Comment: awesome! exactly what I was looking for, I was just about to explode all results from ids that match '%$course%' into an array and match it from there. but luckily I didn't waste any time on that. thanks!!

Comment: may i suggest a schema? because if you have large database, it will perform slow. consider changing it into 3-table design `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add another table `course` in your DB and one more to make the link between `courses` and `users` :

```
Users (id_user, name,  ...)
Courses (id_course, num_course, ...)

userHasCourse (id_user, id_course)
```

`userHasCourse.id_user` and `userHasCourse.id_course` are foreign key of id of Users and Courses table.

You new able to get back all courses info for each user

```
SELECT Users.name, Courses.num_course FROM Courses JOIN userHasCourse USING id_course JOIN Users USING id_user ORDER BY id_user
```

You will get array with all users and associated num_courses.
This solution can be usefull if you want to add more information about courses (more than only one number)

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
WHERE courses IN (12,34,56);
```

Comment: This is the value in the database, he needs to search this value for certain course